# Get Associated BAccount from Contact?

Tags: acumatica

The grid I'm working with has a Selector for a Contact, on input I'm trying to check the associated Contacts Business Account for a my custom date field.

Error
[image]

```cs
    protected void atcProjectDistributionTable_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        var row = (atcProjectDistributionTable)e.Row;
        if (row.ContactID != null)
        {

            Contact con = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<atcProjectDistributionTable.contactID>(cache, row) as Contact;
            row.ContactCD = con.FullName;
            row.BAcc = con.BAccountID;

            if (row.BAcc != null)
            {
                BAccount bAcc = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<atcProjectDistributionTable.bAcc>(cache, row) as BAccount;
                PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt ba = bAcc.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt>();
                if (ba.UsrExpiring != null)
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<atcProjectDistributionTable.bAcc>(cache, row, "Termination date:" + ba.UsrExpiring + "  Reason:" + ba.UsrExReason);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are successfully retrieving the Contact Business Account. The issue is that the BAccount doesn't contain the extension BAccountExt. You should look into why your DAC Extension is not applied to the BAccount DAC.

Comment: Thank you, I can't figure out why, the same code works in the Vendor screen            BAccount bAcc = Base.BAccount.Current;
            PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt ba = bAcc.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt>();

Comment: Please show us your BAccountExt code

Comment: I added a image of my BAccountExt

Comment: The error points at a GetExtension call in RowInserting method ProjectEntry.cs line 1201, perhaps you should look there instead of in the RowUpdated method.

Comment: I have the same code in the row inserted and row updated, So the check is still performed if row contact is updated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what event handler is in question right now: RowInserting, RowInserted or RowUpdated... Based on provided stack trace the error happens because of `bAcc.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt>();` statement invoked when `bAcc` variable equals `null`. Unfortunately, error message is not very descriptive.

As mentioned in [How to call SetPropertyException from another event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926892/how-to-call-setpropertyexception-from-another-event-handler/) thread, none of 3 handlers mentioned here (RowInserting, RowInserted or RowUpdated) should ever be used to report errors or warnings to users. I would highly recommend refactoring your code to follow design of the framework.